# Blocks page and Themekey module

Tags: 6, theming

I am referring to [this page](http://drupal.org/node/721318).

I need to use the administration theme on this page, but this is blocked by default.

At the moment I have to go to the theme page, change to my admin theme, and then change back when I have made the changes I need.

Is there anyway I can set this up using the Themekey module? It is beginning to be a major problem for my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way you can change theme on this location using themekey.

You might consider to do this in your custom module. Something like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init()
{
  global $custom_theme;
  if($_GET['q'] == 'admin/build/blocks'){
    $custom_theme = 'your_theme_name';
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick Question as i have never created a module before. Is there any resources you would suggest on how to learn this?

Comment: I would start from this:

http://drupal.org/developing/modules

Comment: I'd suggest the bible of mod development (http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Drupal-Development-John-VanDyk/dp/1590597559) Also, start reading http://drupal.org/node/231276. I believe Lullabot has some very solid videos on hand for purchase. They always push out a very good product. Quick note, mod development is actually pretty easy once you wrap your head around some basic hooks. Start reading, eating, breathing the Drupal API.